# How to send data using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, forms

My question/issue is on how to send data from a form using JSON to a PHP page. I tried multiple methods but for some reason, it does not work. I believe that I am sending the data incorrectly and that is why I can't receive the data on the PHP page.

This is the code on my login page (uses HTML and JavaScript) :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>UserName and Password</h2>
<form ID = "PassUser">
 Enter UserName:
 <input type="text" id="username" >
 Enter Password:
 <input  type="password" id="password">
 <br><br>
 <input type="submit" value = "Submit" onclick = "submit_form()">
 </form>
 <script>
  function submit_form() {
   var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
   var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
   var data = {}
   data.uname = user;
   data.upass = pass;   
   alert(data.uname);
   alert(data.upass);
   var json_data = JSON.stringify(data);
   alert(json_data);
   var json_upload = "json_name=" + json_data;
   var request= new XMLHttpRequest();
   request.open("POST", "test-middle.php");
   request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   request.send(json_upload);
   };
 </script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

This is the code on the php page:

```html
<?php
$data = $_POST["json_name"];
var_dump($data);
echo $data;
?>
```

The result of the var_dump is NULL.

I need help with try to figure out why I am not receiving data on the PHP page. If the way I'm sending data is correct (don't think it is) or if the way I'm receiving data is correct?
I have also tried `json_decode()` and `file_get_content()` both resulted in NULL. I have been trying to figure this all out for a while and it was not suppose to that long.

Also, the extra lines of code like the alerts are just for me to check if the form data was passing through the JavaScript correctly / at all.

Also, thought the process of how I was doing this: Get the form data and insert it into an object. Then use JSON.stringify(object). Then send it to the PHP page. As for the PHP page, I just wanted to receive the data and echo it out or var_dump it out just to check I received it.

Also, not using JQuery. 
Thank You,
T
Thanks

Edit 1: Changed json_data to json_name. Still outputs NULL.

Comment: Try sending just var data. Dont think you need to stringify it. After which uname and upass are found in $_POST[‘uname’].

Comment: In that case json_upload = {json_name: json_data};

Comment: use mean change `request.send(json_upload)` to `request.send(data)` then in the php page change `$_POST['json_name']` to `$_POST['uname']`. If thats what you mean, I tried it and still got NULL after the var_dump.

Comment: @Nitin tried changing it to `json_upload = {json_name: json_data};` and `json_upload = {'json_name': json_data};` still results as NULL on the php page(side).

Comment: Are you checking the PHP page? or are you checking the page that the JavaScript is on and specifying a place for the reply from the PHP script?

Comment: @AdamMoffat I'm checking the PHP page, to see if the json was sent with the password and username.

Comment: No, THAT is the problem

Comment: The PHP is just running in the background and delivering a response to the current page. The information should be being displayed on the same page as your JavaScript.

Comment: Just fixed my answer and tested.. it works

Comment: Welp I wasted so much time trying to do something that it could not do. Thanks for the help

Comment: Hey man, I forgot to mention but if you're trying to transfer data from page to page you can use the `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: yeah thats why I found it strange that i could not see the data on the php page since I am use to using $_SESSION rather than json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** 
Okay, I got it working, In your HTML file, you need to change

```
<input type="submit" value = "Submit" onclick = "submit_form()">
```

to

```
<button onclick="submit_form()">Submit</button>
```

Also, you're PHP file is trying to return some data but your JavaScript hasn't been programmed to accept it..

You need to add the `request.onreadystatechange` part to ensure that the information is returned from the PHP file once the request has been fulfilled. It is within this function that you want to build the processes for what you want to happen once the submit has been pressed.

You need to create an element in your HTML file for the response to be shown. I created the `<div>` element with `id='response'`. You have to use the ID of that new element to tell the JavaScript where to put the response from the PHP script.

So I edited your HTML file to look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>UserName and Password</h2>
<form ID = "PassUser">
    Enter UserName:
    <input type="text" id="username" >
    Enter Password:
    <input  type="password" id="password">
    <br><br>
    <button onclick="submit_form()">Submit</button>
    </form>
  <div id='response'>
    <!-- THIS IS THE RESPONSE -->
  </div>
    <script>
     function submit_form() {
      var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var user = document.getElementById("username").value;
      var pass = document.getElementById("password").value;
      var data = {};
      data.uname = user;
      data.upass = pass;
      alert(data.uname);
      alert(data.upass);
      var json_data = JSON.stringify(data);
      alert(json_data);
      var json_upload = "json_name=" + json_data;
      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = this.responseText;
          }
        };
      request.open("POST", "test-middle.php", true);
      request.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      request.send(json_upload);
}
    </script>


</body>
</html>
```

After that, as long as your PHP file is kept in the same folder it should work.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks I changed that in my code, but it still results in a output of NULL after the var_dump.

Comment: Check this answer again and let me know

Comment: I tried adding what you said but it still results in NULL. Does it matter if i'm using firefox vs chrome? I don't think it should, but might it be an issue.